# Sharing Temporary Files Between Apps with No SD Card

Tags: android, file, file-io, permissions

If I create a temp file in my application's cache directory I can't, for instance, email it as an attachment. This is because the other app doesn't have permission to read the file.

In API 9 and up, I can set the file to be world readable with setReadable(true, false). unfortunately, I am targetting API level 7+. I don't want to rely on the presence of an SD card, so I can't use the location returned by getExternalStorageDir() to store it in case no card is present.

How can I generate and share a temp file in a way that will work, even with no SD card present?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
final String FILENAME = "file.tmp";
final String someData = "File data";

FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(FILENAME, 
                                      Context.MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE | 
                                      Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
fos.write(someData.getBytes());
fos.close();
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#openFileOutput(java.lang.String,%20int)

Comment: Just as a note, the directory this file is stored in is the one returned by getFilesDir(), *not* getCacheDir(). 

Works like a charm. Thanks!

Comment: It seems that Context.MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE is deprecated as of SDK 17 (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#MODE_WORLD_READABLE)
What is the recommended solution now?

Comment: @alex probably Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION while creating intents.